# Internal server error from YouTube Analytics API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

since yesterday we are receiving code 500 errors from the YouTube Analytics API. Nothing has changed in the relevant code since a few months ago, and everything always went smoothly before yesterday.

This is a sample query (but ALL queries to YT Analytics fail):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D<channelid>&metrics=views,averageViewDuration,estimatedMinutesWatched,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,subscribersGained,subscribersLost&dimensions=channel&start-date=2016-06-01&end-date=2016-06-30&start-index=1
```

(with appropriate channelId and Authorization header set). This is what we are getting back:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.",
    "response": {
        "error": {
            "errors": [{
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "internalError",
                    "message": "Unknown error occurred on the server."
                }
            ],
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Unknown error occurred on the server."
        }
    }
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that we started seeing these 500s on Monday Nov 7, 2016 a day before they announced a new feature rollout? https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2016/11/download-your-ad-revenue-reports.html  Our analytics calls are all b0rked as you have described above. Very frustrating.

Comment: It would be nice if we could find out if Google is even aware of this problem and is looking into it.

Comment: Things suddenly started working again for me today.  No code changes made.  I really hope this API becomes more stable going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem : "Error 500" for any youtube API called (yt-analytics.readonly).

Here is a workaround for fixing the problem :

1. Add the following right on your application https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly, even if it's not usefull
2. re-generate the refresh token
3. everything is fixed

You can even remove the application and add it again wihtout the youtube.readonly right, it's still working. It's like the API got an update by adding this unusefull right.

I have also tested another workaround with the API Test Console, by adding "Google APIs Explorer" application with the youtube.readonly & yt-analytics.readonly unblock the problem and you dont have any "Error 500" with your own token.

Hope this helps and it's clear enought !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it mostly fixed this problem.
I think the problem is on YouTube side.
We are still waiting until they fix 100%.

Comment: We have been noticed that all errors are fixed now. Since we haven't  touch any source codes or tokens, it seems the error was on YouTube's side.